# componet not unmounting when route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, mobx-react

I have react app which has multiple routes. there are 2 routes that take array of paths. when there is one the app works correctly but when there are 2 routes that each have array of path, some components will not unmount.I am using mobx for passing data. When i open the **AttachmentForm** through both ***createAttachment*** or ***'/manage/attachment/:id***' and go back using browser back button the form componet will still appear at the top of other components

```
import { Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import NavBar from '../../features/nav/NavBar';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { Route, withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from '../../features/home/HomePage';
import AttachmentDashboard from '../../features/attachments/dashboard/AttachmentDashboard';
import AttachmentForm from '../../features/attachments/form/AttachmentForm';
import AttachmentDetails from '../../features/attachments/details/AttachmentDetails';

import AddressDashboard from '../../features/addresses/dashboard/AddressDashboard';
import AddressForm from '../../features/addresses/form/AddressForm';
import AddressDetails from '../../features/addresses/details/AddressDetails';
const App: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ location }) => {

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
      <Route
        path={'/(.+)'}
        render={() => (
          <Fragment>
            <NavBar />
            <Container style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
              <Route exact path='/attachments' component={AttachmentDashboard} />
              <Route exact path='/attachments/:id' component={AttachmentDetails} />
              <Route
                key={location.key}
                exact path={['/createAttachment', '/manage/attachment/:id']}
                component={AttachmentForm}
              />
              <Route exact path='/addresses' component={AddressDashboard} />
              <Route exact path='/addresses/:id' component={AddressDetails} />
              <Route
                key={location.key}
                exact path={['/createAddress', '/manage/address/:id']}
                component={AddressForm}
              />
            </Container>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default withRouter(observer(App));
```

Comment: Your code seems fine at the first sight. Maybe you could reproduce it on http://codesandbox.io/ with minimal example? Just 2 routes and 2 components, some thing like this. One thing you could improve is to use `<Switch>` more. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: Thank you. Adding switch fixed it.but why did i need switch? shouldn't the exact path block other components from rendering?

Comment: Yep, I am also not completely sure why, all your paths are unique and use exact so it is kinda weird that it helped. But usually using `Switch` is a good thing because you don't need to check that every path is unique and stuff like that in the future.